# Adding classic code behind asp.net page to asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one asp.net page. I want to add this page to asp.net mvc 3. I mean I have one just page and I want to display this page with creating new asp.net mvc 3 project.

I found some similar questions but they didn't work.  I created class and transfered code behind part from my original page. Then I created view ,and transfered html part.

I added this line to beginning of my view.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Asignment.Views.Shared.View" %>
```

And my class file start like this;

```
namespace Asignment.Views.Home.view
```

//namespace Asignment.Models
    {
    public class view:ViewUserControl

My biggest problem is that in class file my code does not recognize fields and variables which are from view.
Can you fixed if is there a mistake and can you give some idea.

Thank you very much

Comment: can you tell what you are intending to do

Comment: I have one page which I completed with asp.net 4. It works. I wrote cith c# and there 10-15 code behind lines and some text box and one submit button. And now I want to create new asp.net mvc3 project and add this page. But I dont know mvc3 and I dont have time to learn. How can I transfer this page. This is not big project, it is just one page

Comment: "But I dont know mvc3 and I dont have time to learn." ... then DON'T do any MVC - projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually there shouldn't be a problem adding a Web Forms page to an MVC project.

You should start by adding a new Web Form from the "Add New Item..." menu in the solution explorer. **Make sure you don't add it inside a View Folder.**

If this Web Forms page doesn't work, you could start by checking your routing setup in Global.asax.cs. **Make sure that routes.RouteExistingFiles isn't set to true**.

Comment: But when I start application, program first look home controller and look index. how can I start this application if I cannot put it in view folder. I dont know anything mvc3 ,can you explain more please

Comment: Web Form pages are called outside the MVC pipeline. So by placing your Web Form at the application's root level, you can access it directly using the page's name. (like /WebForm1.aspx). This Web Form page will have NOTHING to do with your controllers, actions or MVC views (other than being in the same application.)